# Ryzen Motherboard with ECC support

Tags: motherboard, memory

I am looking at doing a NAS build with Ryzen 3 or 5.  I read that Ryzen supports ECC if the motherboard supports it.  Do any ECC Ryzen Motherboards exist?  According to PC Part Picker, no boards with ECC support exist.

Comment: To be extra clear: [Ryzen isn't validated for ECC support on consumer chipsets and, as a result, AMD doesn't officially support it.](http://www.hardwarecanucks.com/forum/hardware-canucks-reviews/75030-ecc-memory-amds-ryzen-deep-dive.html) ECC support is however enabled, and certain motherboard manufactures do validate ECC memory.

Answer (score 1):

This [post](http://www.overclock.net/t/1629642/ryzen-ecc-motherboards) provides a list.

I don't know how accurate it is or up-to-date, its dated May, so...

But on the list, which will help give you a starting point for your search:

> *ASRock* -All x370 support [Not confirmed to actually run in ECC mode] ECC unbuffered [Unconfirmed Windows support, Claimed support in Linux >= 4.10]
>
> X370 Taichi -Linux 4.10 ECC support listed on QVL
>
> X370 Killer SLI/ac
>
> X370 Killer SLI
>
> Fatal1ty X370 Professional Gaming lists 3 ECC chips in QVL
>
> Fatal1ty X370 Gaming K4
>
> *ASUS -Support for ECC unbuffered*
>
> PRIME B350-PLUS
>
> PRIME X370-PRO -3rd party claim -3rd party claim 2 Transcend ECC chips listed on Official QVL

Comment: There's at least one error on that list: Asus's [specification page for the PRIME B350-A/CSM](https://www.asus.com/us/Motherboards/PRIME-B350M-A-CSM/specifications/) says no ECC.

Comment: And I said I don't know how accurate it was.  My answer still answers OP question.  If one on the list is incorrect and the others are correct, that answers OP.  I removed it from this answer, but the source list is still going to be what it is.